# Variable spacing between mathop and its argument

Tags: math-operators, white-space

The MWE below defines and uses the *-suffixed form `\card*` of the math operator `\card` to create greater spacing after "card" when the following argument is something like "(" or "[" that otherwise would print too close to it.

Is there a better way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\card*{\card\,}

\begin{document}

$\card \mathbb{R} = \card* (0, 1) = \card* [0, 1] = \card R$

\end{document}
```

**Added:** The same issue arises with respect to `\sup`, `\inf`, `\max`, `\min` when the argument is an interval.

Comment: by declaring `\card` to be `\MathOperator` (`\mathop`) you are explicitly specifying the standard tex layout which would insert a thin space between `\card` and a letter and no space between `\card` and a `mathopen` if you don't want that, there is no advantage (and only disadvantages) in declaring it with `DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: if you don't want the standard spacing just use `\newcommand\card{\mathrm{card}\,}`

Comment: Let me come with a completely different suggestion: Always use parenthesis after math operators. So write `\card(R)`, `\card([0,1])`, and `\card((0,1))`, as well as `\sin(\theta)`. It’s clear, it’s consistent, and you don’t run into dilemmas like the one you mention.

Comment: @Gaussler: Yes, always using parentheses would give a consistent syntax but runs afoul of traditional math notation such as sin x.

Comment: @egreg As a mathematician, my impression is that `sin(x)` is becoming increasingly common among mathematicians, as it’s more consistent with general math notation. I most often encounter the notation `sin x` in calculus and physics literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perhaps want this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\cardop}{card}
\newcommand{\card}{\cardop{}}

\begin{document}

$\card \mathbb{R} = \card (0, 1) = \card [0, 1] = \card R$

$\exp\card X$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `\card` at the end of a formula.

On the other hand, the command would not do the intended job for

```
\card(A \cup B)
```

where the parentheses are actual delimiters of a complex formula.

So my suggestion is to define instead a command for intervals to make them ordinary atoms:

```
\newcommand{\intv}[1]{{#1}}
```

and use `\card\intv{(0,1)}` with `\card` defined as a usual operator.

Comment: By saying "Don't use `\card` at the end of a formula," do you mean simply not to do something like `c = \card`? If so, of course not, since `\card` is meant to be a mathop and hence always to have an argument -- just like, e.g., `\sup`.

Comment: @murray I added a suggestion: it's not `\card` that you want to modify, but intervals.

Comment: @murray I think egreg’s point was that you don’t want to write something like “`we denote by~$\card$ the cardinality`”, since this is, indeed, at the end of a formula.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of `\DeclareMathOperator` is to produce the spacing that you are preventing with the `*` form.  The intention is to add a thin space before a letter so log *x*  but no space is needed for log(*x*)

If you want to avoid the standard layout and have a thin space in all cases no need to have a separate markup with a star-form, just do not declare the command to be a math operator:

[image]

The first form looks more natural to me, but define whichever way you prefer,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\DeclareMathOperator{\cardA}{card}

\newcommand\cardB{\mathrm{card}\,}

\begin{document}


$\cardA \mathbb{R} = \cardA (0, 1) = \cardA [0, 1] = \cardA R$


$\cardB \mathbb{R} = \cardB (0, 1) = \cardB [0, 1] = \cardB R$

\end{document}
```