# Simplify \SplitArgument construction?

Tags: xparse, arguments

I want to exploit the `interval` package to obtain "French" notation for intervals, that is, with an open interval appearing as "]0, 1[", etc. But the package's `\interval` command is awkward to type, requiring two separate arguments for an interval's endpoints as well as possibly an option for the type of interval, as in:

```
 \interval[open]{0}{1}
```

I would like to simpllify the command so as to obtain the same result but typing more simply the following...

```
 \intvo{0,1}
```

...with a single argument consisting of the two endpoints separated by a comma.

The definition of `\intvo` in the following MWE uses `xparse` to accomplish this — but the definition seems too complicated, involving a 3rd argument I never intend to use.

**Question:** How can I simplify the definition so as to eliminate the seemingly supfluous `\IfValueT{#3}{}` ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{interval}

\NewDocumentCommand{\intvo}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{,}} m }{\printintvo#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printintvo}{mmm}{\interval[open]{#1}{#2}\IfValueT{#3}{}}

\begin{document}

$\intvo{0,1}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\SplitArgument{1}{,}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Then how do I change the definition of `\printintvo`?

Comment: Remove the third argument: `\NewDocumentCommand{\printintvo}{mm}{\interval[open]{#1}{#2}}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Got it! Make your comments an Answer, please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `\SplitArgument` reads:

> [image: This processor splits the argument given at each occurrence of the ⟨tokens⟩ up to a maximum of ⟨number⟩ tokens (thus dividing the input into ⟨number⟩ + 1 parts). An error is given if too many ⟨tokens⟩ are present in the input. The processed input is placed inside ⟨number⟩ + 1 sets of braces for further use. If there are fewer than {⟨number⟩} of {⟨tokens⟩} in the argument then -NoValue- markers are added at the end of the processed argument.]

That is, the `<number>` is the number of *separators*, not the number of items, so you should process the argument with `\SplitArgument{1}{,}`.  Then you just have to remove the extra argument in `\printintvo`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{interval}

\NewDocumentCommand{\intvo}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}} m }{\printintvo#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printintvo}{mm}{\interval[open]{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

$\intvo{0,1}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: To avoid insufficient space between a math operator such as a defined `\card` and an interval argument (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605171/variable-spacing-between-mathop-and-its-argument), it would be better to modify the second `\NewDocumentCommand` to enclose its last argument in an extra pair of braces: `\NewDocumentCommand{\printintvo}{mm}{{\interval[open]{#1}{#2}}}`.

Comment: Ditto for an already defined math operator such as `\sup` or `\max`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `interval` wants so many arguments in order to allow for changing the inner separator. If you don't want to, `\SplitArgument` is not necessary.

Here's a modification of what I use in my notes (of course I ***don't*** use the perverse French style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\intv}{somm}
 {
  {% make the object an ordinary atom
  \keys_set:nn { murray/intv } { #3 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% auto sizing
    \__murray_intv:NNn \left \right { #4 }
   }
   {% normal
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {
      \__murray_intv:NNn \mathopen \mathclose { #4 }
     }
     {
      \__murray_intv:ccn { \cs_to_str:N #2 l } { \cs_to_str:N #2 r } { #4 }
     }
   }
  }% end of ordinary atom
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__murray_intv:NNn
 {
  #1\l__murray_intv_left_tl #3 #2\l__murray_intv_right_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__murray_intv:NNn { cc }

\tl_new:N \l__murray_intv_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l__murray_intv_right_tl

\keys_define:nn { murray/intv }
 {
    o .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { ] }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { [ },
  oo .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { ] }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { [ },
  c .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { ] },
  cc .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { ] },
  oc .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { ] }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { ] },
  co .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { [ },
  o  .value_forbidden:n = true,
  oo .value_forbidden:n = true,
  c  .value_forbidden:n = true,
  cc .value_forbidden:n = true,
  oc .value_forbidden:n = true,
  co .value_forbidden:n = true,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\intv{o}{0,1}$
$\intv{c}{0,1}$
$\intv{oo}{0,1}$
$\intv{oc}{0,1}$
$\intv{co}{0,1}$
$\intv{cc}{0,1}$

$\intv[\big]{o}{0,1}$
$\intv[\big]{c}{0,1}$
$\intv[\Big]{oo}{0,1}$
$\intv[\Big]{oc}{0,1}$
$\intv[\bigg]{co}{0,1}$
$\intv[\bigg]{cc}{0,1}$

$\intv*{o}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{c}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{oo}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{oc}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{co}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{cc}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$

\end{document}
```

You can define abbreviations such as

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\intvo}{m}{\intv{o}{#1}}
```

but I believe that having a generic command that can size the fences is better.

[image]

If you want to be able to configure the separator, you can use `\SplitArgument` as follows; modify the inner separator to suit you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\intv}{s o m >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}
 {
  {% make the object an ordinary atom
  \keys_set:nn { murray/intv } { #3 }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% auto sizing
    \__murray_intv:NNnn \left \right #4
   }
   {% normal
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {
      \__murray_intv:NNnn \mathopen \mathclose #4
     }
     {
      \__murray_intv:ccnn { \cs_to_str:N #2 l } { \cs_to_str:N #2 r } #4
     }
   }
  }% end of ordinary symbol
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__murray_intv:NNnn
 {
  #1\l__murray_intv_left_tl     % left fence
  #3                            % start of interval
  ,                             % inner separator
  #4 #2\l__murray_intv_right_tl % right fence
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__murray_intv:NNnn { cc }

\tl_new:N \l__murray_intv_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l__murray_intv_right_tl

\keys_define:nn { murray/intv }
 {
    o .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { ] }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { [ },
  oo .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { ] }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { [ },
  c .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { ] },
  cc .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { ] },
  oc .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { ] }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { ] },
  co .code:n =
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_left_tl { [ }
   \tl_set:Nn \l__murray_intv_right_tl { [ },
  o  .value_forbidden:n = true,
  oo .value_forbidden:n = true,
  c  .value_forbidden:n = true,
  cc .value_forbidden:n = true,
  oc .value_forbidden:n = true,
  co .value_forbidden:n = true,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\intv{o}{0,1}$
$\intv{c}{0,1}$
$\intv{oo}{0,1}$
$\intv{oc}{0,1}$
$\intv{co}{0,1}$
$\intv{cc}{0,1}$

$\intv[\big]{o}{0,1}$
$\intv[\big]{c}{0,1}$
$\intv[\Big]{oo}{0,1}$
$\intv[\Big]{oc}{0,1}$
$\intv[\bigg]{co}{0,1}$
$\intv[\bigg]{cc}{0,1}$

$\intv*{o}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{c}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{oo}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{oc}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{co}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$
$\intv*{cc}{\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why go to such lengths to turn `\big` and friends into strings and then attach `l` and `r` to them and turn them back into commands? Is `\bigl` not just equivalent to `\mathopen\big` and `\bigr` to `\mathclose\big`? Why not just print `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` before them?

Comment: @Gaussler Possibly. But this would make assumptions on how `\bigl` and friends are defined. Currently it's like that, but maybe higher level packages such as `unicode-math` might decide differently.

Comment: Well, do tell me if they start changing that, for I’m using the `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` solution in `semantex`.

Comment: The reason I prefer to use the `interval` package is that it allows toggling between "French" notation (outward-opening square brackets for open intervals) rather than the more common notation (parentheses). The definitions in your answer seem to hard-code the choice. Presumably a switch could be added to it, but what is the advantage of your approach to using the `interval` package together with a `\SplitArgument` construction to simplify the notation?