# writting a new command in Latex

Tags: macros

I want to write this command below in a new shorter command

`\numrange[⟨options⟩]{⟨numbers⟩}{⟨number2⟩}`

I want to write it like

`\nums{number - number}`

or anything similar

for example,
`\numrange[⟨options⟩]{20}{30}`
and the new command will be like
`\nums{20-30}`

output:
`20-30`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've got.

Comment: Similar question [arguments - Easy way to convert \command{x}{y} to \command{x,y} - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647164/easy-way-to-convert-commandxy-to-commandx-y?noredirect=1&lq=1) (99% of the answers there should be portable here)

Comment: The subject line does not really inform about the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the argument processors built into `ltcmd`/`xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand \nums { O{} >{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m }
  {\numrange[{#1}]#2}

\newcommand\numrange[3][]{from #2 to #3}

\begin{document}
\nums{3-10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're indeed using `siunitx` you could consider using this instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \nums { O{} >{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#1}
      \siunitx_number_range:nn #2
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\nums{3-10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite likely, the OP is using `\numrange` from `siunitx`.

Comment: @egreg likely yes... But do we know? No. Does it matter for the answer? Also no. :)

Comment: Well yes, as if it's using `siunitx` v3 there is a code-level API that new document commands should be using ;)

Comment: @JosephWright which isn't documented in `siunitx.pdf` :P Imho, you should include the `expl3`-level in the documentation (I know there is `siunitx-code.pdf`. Btw. what would be the correct way to set the options? Via `\sisetup`?)

Comment: @Skillmon I can add a link or comment, but adding the entire programmers API docs seems overkill. I'd use `\keys_set:nn { siunitx }` at the code level,; there's not really document level way that fits into what LaTeX itself documents (`\begingroup`/`\endgroup` are not after all in Lamport's book).

Comment: @Skillmon Huh? That's the documented interface in `siunitx-code.pdf`; like I said, the issue with using `\sisetup` in a document-level command is that there is _no_ documented group command in LaTeX, only environments.

Comment: Oh, see that's what happens if one searches for too specific stuff using a search function :P

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, `\def` primitive is the right tool for solving your issue.

```
\def\nums #1{\numsA #1;}
\def\numsA #1-#2;{from #1 to #2}

test: \nums{3-10}
```